# Unpack list and cast at the same time

Tags: python, list, casting

I have a long list of stings which need to be passed into a function as integers.  What I am doing right now is:

```
my_function(int(list[0]), int(list[1]), int(list[2]), int(list[3])...)
```

But I know I can make a much shorter function call by unpacking the list:

```
my_function(*list)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to combine `int()` casting with list unpacking `*`, something like this:

```
my_function(*int(list))  #Doesn't work
```

Comment: Your last line was very close tho' - you just need to make all the values in the list ``int``s which is where the ``map`` comes in @Thorsten is showing the way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the built-in method `map`, e.g.

```
my_function(*map(int, list))
```

Alternatively, try list-comprehension:

```
my_function(*[int(x) for x in list])
```

BTW:

Please don't use `list` as name for a local variable, this will hide the built-in method `list`.

It is common use to append an underscore for variable-names that would otherwise hide built-in methods / conflict with keywords.

Comment: This is one of the nice things in Python. When you learn about it, you say "Wow", and when you have to go back to a language that doesn't have such features, you say "#@+*%&". So be prepared for that.

Answer (score 3):

mapping is the answer:

```
map(int, my_list)
```